# nodejs "killed" but memoryUsage shows low value

Tags: node.js, memory

I have a streaming processor that keeps getting "Killed".

I've limited the process to 512MB since that should be plenty for what I'm doing

```bash
node --max-old-space-size=512 ./scrapers/AcquireFacts.js
```

Originally, I assumed it was due to large memory consumption and did a bunch of memory investigation and optimization, resolving many of the issues, and seemed to have it under control.

Unfortunately, as I let the process run for (expected) days, it terminated with the message "Killed".

As part of the memory issues, I implemented a subroutine that periodically outputs the memory consumption.

```js
setInterval(()=>{
    let used = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed
    used /= (1024**2);
    used = Math.floor(used);
    membar.update(used,{label:'RAM (MB)'});
},512);
```

It hovers around 45MB of consumption at any given time, and at the moment of failure shows a value in that range

```
|████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░| RAM (MB)          | 46/512   | 1h11m |
|███░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░| AcquireFact (484) | 495/7344 | 1h10m |
```

I'm a little stumped.

- Is there a better way to measure memory?
- Is there something other than memory that could be causing the kill?

**Possibly relevant**

- process is downloading a zip, extracting one file at a time, and loading it into an S3 instance
- still suspicious of a memory leak as temp files are not being cleaned up
- `top` agrees with the 45MB, but `qps` shows 2GB
- there are 6 concurrent awaits at any time, a new one is added to the buffer each time one finishes

Comment: Make sure you're catching all errors. Uncaught errors is one reason for node to kill itself

Comment: Doesn't that usually die with "unhandled exception in promise"?